# Abandon/forsake/leave?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am a bit confused as to where I should use "abandon", "forsake" and "leave".
According to my searches in dictionaries:

Forsake: to leave someone , especially when you should stay because they need you.

Leave: to go away from a place or person

Abandon: 1.to leave a person especially someone you're responsible for.
2.to go away from a place , vehicle etc permanently especially because the situation makes it impossible for you to stay.
( definitions from Longman dictionary)

So it seems to me that there is a nuance here. At first glance the conclusion I drew, was that "forsake" is used when "a person" is left ,while  "abandon" and "leave" are more general ,as according to definitions they are used to say "a person" or "a place" is left, but today I was reading some materials and I came across this sentence:

*much of new England in the late nineteenth century presented a discouraging picture of abandoned farms and sickly villages as people **forsook** the countryside and rushed to the larger towns and cities*

It seems a bit odd that "forsake" is used for getting across this concept that a countryside is deserted. Personally, I used to think that the use of " leave" or "abandon" would be more suitable in this case, so it made me question my former speculations about the use of these 3 words again.

Now I hope you can cast light on the difference of these 3 words.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a good dictionary. "Abandon" and "forsake" are fairly close synonyms. But "leave" does not mean the same thing - it is mostly used to describe a temporary, or even a repeated action "He leaves home for work at 7.30 every morning".

Comment: @WS2 Not necessarily. _Forsake_ is a rather dramatic, literary word. You might say "His wife has left him', but you probably wouldn't say that she had forsaken him in everyday conversation.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree that it is a dramatic literary word, sometimes carrying a strong emotive message. But I would have said "forsake" was fairly close in meaning to "abandon". But the OP does need a dictionary in order to fully master these meanings.

Comment: @WS2 the definitions I provided ,are from Longman dictionary. Longman is one the reliable English dictionaries.what I asked was the difference between these words I already know that "forsake" is more formal but I wanna know if there is any semantic difference here.

Comment: @Lara It is very difficult in a forum such as this to explain and teach the contexts in which different words are used. To some extent it involves wide reading and experience with the language. All I can say is that in the passage you quoted, both "abandoned" and "forsook" are used in perfectly appropriate ways. And they are so synonymous that one could exchange their positions so as to write *...sickly farms and forsaken villages, as people abandoned the countryside...*

Comment: @WS2 ok ,forget about my example. Tell me, if you use these two words interchangeably as a native. I checked your profile and it seems you live in UK. So tell me about your experience. In which cases do you often hear each word from natives. Someone has answered my question and he says forsake is usually used for human and abandon usually is used for things. He told me that it is a bit awkward to say that a land is forsaken. Do you confirm this saying as a native?

Comment: @WS2 in comments above you said that "leave" is usually used to talk about a temporary repeated action , but in my own experience I have seen many cases(in movies, stories ,articles ,etc) in which"leave" was used to show permanent action not temporary.

Comment: @Lara Yes. "Leave" is used both for permanent and temporary actions.

Comment: @Lara "Forsake" is not a word I would use every day. The OED has four main senses and a number of sub-senses. The one which has most relevance today is perhaps sense 4a-*To abandon, leave entirely, withdraw from; esp. to withdraw one's presence and help or companionship from; to desert. †to forsake patch: ? to quit the spot.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Abandon" and "Forsake" imply permanence. In your example the people who forsook farms and villages are not coming back. Similarly the owner of an abandoned car doesn't want it any more.

"Leave" can be both permanent ("*I left home when I was 18*") and temporary ("*I leave home every morning at 7:30*")

Although "Abandon" and "Forsake" can be applied to both places/things and persons it is more usual to find places/things abandoned and people forsaken. But, of course, your example is an exception to this generalisation. Another exception is children for whom parents cannot be found are abandoned, not forsaken.

Forsaken also has overtones of personal involvement such as in the song "*Do not forsake me oh my darling*" whilst abandonment is less personal, the thing is just discarded or unwanted. Again a generalisation, not a fixed rule.